# integrate the improper function in (0,1)

Tags: integration

Find $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ hwere

$f(x) = 2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$, $x$ in $(0,1)$

```
       0, for all other values
```

Comment: what is $f(x)$?

Comment: 2xsin(1/x-cos(1/x)) IN.(0,1)

Comment: i got $\sin(1)$ for this integral

Comment: Here is meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ for properly displaying functions.

Comment: Can you please use Mathjax? Also, I believe you don't know what improper integrals are.